# convert jpg to pdf

Tags: pdf, convert, imagemagick

in my Ubuntu 19.10  when trying to convert `.jpg` to `.pdf`  :

convert gives :

```
joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ convert ‘/home/joso/Desktop/Marticeva etaziranje/IMG_20200104_102541.jpg’ output.pdf
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPG’ @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
convert: no images defined `output.pdf’ @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.
```

I can open jpg file. In terminal:

```
joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ file /home/joso/Desktop/Marticeva\ etaziranje/IMG_20200104_102541.jpg
/home/joso/Desktop/Marticeva etaziranje/IMG_20200104_102541.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=10, manufacturer=HUAWEI, model=ATU-L21, xresolution=150, yresolution=158, resolutionunit=2, software=ATU-L21-user 8.0.0 HUAWEIATU-L21 156(C432) release-keys, datetime=2020:01:04 10:25:41, GPS-Data], baseline, precision 8, 3120x4160, components 3
joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$
```

using command :

```
joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ cp /home/joso/Desktop/Marticeva\ etaziranje/IMG_20200104_102541.jpg foo.jpg; convert foo.jpg foo.pdf 
convert: no decode delegate for this image format JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562. 
convert: no images definedfoo.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273. 
joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$
```

still the same, no success.

I tried with 2 other files:

```
joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ convert '/home/joso/Pictures/IMG_20191214_120216.jpg'  output.pdf
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
convert: no images defined `output.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.

joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ convert '/home/joso/Pictures/John Selman2.jpeg' output.pdf
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
convert: no images defined `output.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.

joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ convert /home/joso/Pictures/IMG_20191214_120216.jpg output.pdf
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
convert: no images defined `output.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.
joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ 


joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ convert -compress jpeg /home/joso/Pictures/IMG_20191214_120216.jpg /home/joso/Pictures/output.pdf convert: no decode delegate for this image format JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562. convert: no images defined/home/joso/Pictures/output.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.
```

I can open the file in an image viewer and `file` reports it's a normal jpg:

```
$ file /home/joso/Desktop/Marticeva\ etaziranje/IMG_20200104_102541.jpg 
/home/joso/Desktop/Marticeva etaziranje/IMG_20200104_102541.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=10, manufacturer=HUAWEI, model=ATU-L21, xresolution=150, yresolution=158, resolutionunit=2, software=ATU-L21-user 8.0.0 HUAWEIATU-L21 156(C432) release-keys, datetime=2020:01:04 10:25:41, GPS-Data], baseline, precision 8, 3120x4160, components 3
```

I also tried this as suggested in the comments:

```
$ convert -compress jpeg /home/joso/Pictures/IMG_20191214_120216.jpg    
/home/joso/Pictures/output.pdf convert: no decode delegate for this image format JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562. convert: no images defined/home/joso/Pictures/output.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make the last one probably echo $MAGICK_HOME - for me that variable is not set. Check what formats are supported: `identify -list format | grep JPG`. I expect an installation issue here.

Comment: I solved this problem by reinstalling fresh Ubuntu 19.10 from live USB, and than installing  ImageMagic-6 . After that I changed in etc/ImageMagic-6/policy.xml
by adding line:

 <policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PDF" />

and changing to:

 <policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PDF" />

now it works  !

Comment: @user3140225 reinstalling Ubuntu 19.10 obviously is not a valid solution to this problem! Perhaps only changing the policy line would do the trick? Anyway, since a reinstall has been done, there is no use to investigate this problem further.

Answer (score 6):

Keep it simple.  Open your jpg file with libre office draw (or impress).  Once open in the menu "file" (i suppose in English) export this file with " export  as pdf")

Comment: While this might work for a single file, it is obviously not practical for batch processing. Nor does it address the real issue of why `convert` is failing. The OP's command should work, there's something strange going on.

Comment: Not an appropriate answer: question is on basic core functionality of the "convert" utility. And yes, it becomes quite less efficient if yo need to handle 100 files in a folder. After all, it is a computer we use, and we want the computer to do the tedious work.

Comment: I cannot read that it handles over more than one jpg.  The question is not clear.

Comment: You can  use Master pdf editor (for free in Linux) :Create PDF documents from scanned documents / existing files .  Download:  "https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/download-master-pdf-editor-4-for-linux.html"

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

then you use somethin like this with the files in WORKINGDIRECTORY (`cd /path/to/workingdirectory/`)

```
convert input.jpg output.pdf
```

if it aint working like u aint got permission or somethin u gotta change the config file to allow that convert function to do that.
you do that by sain `sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` and then you go to hashtag out this line `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />` and maybe the JPG line too.